# POST request using angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-resource

In my `index.js` file I have the following POST...

```
router.route('/bears')
// create a bear (accessed at POST http://localhost:8080/api/bears)
.post(function(req, res) {

    var bear = new Bear();      // create a new instance of the Bear model
    bear.name = req.body.name;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)

    // save the bear and check for errors
    bear.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
    });

})
.get(function(req, res) {
    Bear.find(function(err, bears) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(bears);
    });
});
```

I test the url `http://localhost:8080/api/bears` with a `POST` request on Postman and it was successful. Now I'd like to test my `POST` request using angular `$resource`.

I tried the following which I got from the documentation...

```
app.factory('Profile', function ($resource) {
    var Bear = $resource('http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000/api/bears/:bearId', {bearId:'@id'});
    var single_bear = Bear.post({bearId:123}, function(){
        single_bear.name = "Yogi";
        single_bear.$save();
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what I should for `bearId`, I just put a random number. And I am trying to save the bear's name as `Yogi`. I'm assuming this `POST` request will occur when I run the app, but I do so and then check to see if my db was filled and there is no entry.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

in case you're wondering what a bear entry looks like...

```
{
    "_id": "57ded2302a5ebc050ce3852d",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": ""
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource is configured to look for the `id` property in the data passed (via `'@id'`) yet your data is passing `bearId`.

Additionally, the data from your server seems to have an `_id` property, not `id` nor `bearId`.

Also, the resource method you're looking for is `save()`, not `post()`.

---

I'd go with this type of resource definition...

```
$resource('http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:3000/api/bears/:id', {id:'@_id'});
```

Then, you can use it to create a new Bear via

```
Bear.save({_id: 123, name: 'Yogi'})
```